# How do I make my search function in asp.net print everything correctly?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make a search option which will pull out user data from my OleDb database, it works but 
**the result is something like:**

```
tripleUser  
tripleUser
tripleUser  False
```

**While the expected result should've looks like:**

```
tripleUser  False
tripleUser  True
tripleUser  False
```

As you can see, only the last user boolean is printed, why is that happening?

```
int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
   for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i ++)
       {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        Label label = new Label();
        while(tReader.Read())
             {
              label.Text = tReader.GetString(0);
              cell.Controls.Add(label);
              row.Cells.Add(cell);
              cell = new TableCell();
              label = new Label();
              label.Text = tReader.GetBoolean(1).ToString();
              cell.Controls.Add(label);
              row.Cells.Add(cell);
              table.Rows.Add(row);
              row = new TableRow();
              cell = new TableCell();                                            
             }
        TableHolder.Controls.Add(table);
       }
```

I used debugging mode and a breakpoint to determine if everything is working as expected and everything is working as expected, meaning that this is a UI problem.

Comment: Please provide the full code you've used to show the results

Comment: Edited it to include the full code :)

Comment: What is the expected result should've looks like ?

Comment: First user should be false, second user should be true and last user should be false and only the last user boolean is printed.

Comment: What is the boolean field Name ?? could it be DBNull ?

Comment: Makes no sense since the last user boolean is printed and I get no errors. The field name is admin. That is the query: OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT uName, admin FROM ArcadeDatabase WHERE uName LIKE '%" + SearchUsr.Text + "%'", con

Comment: have you verified (by debugging/breaking) that the data is as you expect within the `tReader` object? Need to isolate the problem to the right step in the code. Possible issues: data is not in the database as you expect, query is not reading from the database as you expect, or data is not rendering to the UI as you expect. debugging will help you understand at which stage it's occurring. If you've already verified this and the problem is definitely in the UI then you should state this in the question.

Comment: Thanks, just did that and everything is as expected, so the problem is in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `admin` field might be **DBNull**, in that case you can avoid that and returns false :

```
 Boolean flag = tReader["admin"] as bool? ?? false;
    if(flag)
    {
        label.Text="True";
    }
    else
    {
        label.Text="False";
    }
```

**EDIT**

> All you needed is to set an instance to the **row**, **cell** and **label** inside the loop.

```
row = new TableRow();    
cell = new TableCell();                  
label = new Label();

label.Text = tReader.GetString(0);
cell.Controls.Add(label);
row.Cells.Add(cell);

cell = new TableCell();
label = new Label();

label.Text = tReader.GetBoolean(1).ToString();
cell.Controls.Add(label);
row.Cells.Add(cell);

table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but after running the code in the debug mode with a breakpoint the label gets the required value but it isn't showing in the UI. That means that the field is not DBNull

Comment: Wow, thanks :D I don't get the difference between the codes though, can you please explain the difference?

Comment: The differences i made are setting an instance to the Objects inside the loop.@Itay080